# Showing elements on jQuery Masonry

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

Does anybody know how I can do this?

```
┌---------------------------------┐#content
| ┌-------------┐ ┌-------------┐ |
| |         [.A]| |[.B]         | |
| |             | |             | |             
| |             | |             | |
| └-------------┘ |             | |
| ┌-------------┐ |             | |
| |         [.A]| |             | | 
| |             | |             | |
| |             | └-------------┘ |
| └-------------┘ ┌-------------┐ |                 
|                 |[.B]         | |
|                 |             | |
|                 |             | |
|                 └-------------┘ |
└---------------------------------┘
```

I have a div(#content) that has masonized divs(.oddpost) in it. It's two column so it goes only either on the right or on the left. Now what I want to do is make a div(.A) appear on the .oddposts that goes to the left and make another div(.B) appear on the ones that goes to the left.

.A and .B are both inside .oddpost but both are initially hidden. I want to make them "show" depending on their position. I've tried using position and offset but it takes effect on the .oddpost when they're not using masonry then renders the masonry so it's a little confusing. Is there any way to acheive this using jQuery?

Comment: I think if you'd share some Code on what you have done already, somebody could help you more.

Comment: I found this tutorial, that mostly does what you want: http://www.9lessons.info/2012/01/facebook-timeline-design-using-jquery.html

Answer (score 0):

Create the divs in sequential order in your html file, then apply this to the two A's blocks

```
.A {
 float: left;
 }
```

inside a div which is floating to the left, and apply this to the B's blocks

```
 .B {
  float: right;
  }
```

inside a div block which aligned to the right inside your *css* file and see if it's going to work for you. See this example http://jsfiddle.net/nawar/gg24L/